# How to write an apply() function that only applies to odd-numbered columns in r matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, apply

Suppose we have a "test" matrix that looks like this: (1,2,3, 4,5,6, 7,8,9, 10,11,12) generated by running `test <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 4)`. A simple 3 x 4 (rows x columns) matrix of numbers running from 1 to 12.

Now suppose we'd like to add a value of 1 to each element in each *odd-numbered* matrix column, so we end up with a matrix of the following values: (2,3,4, 4,5,6, 8,9,10, 10,11,12). How would we use an `apply()` function to do this?

Note that this is a simplified example. In the more complete code I'm working with, the matrix dynamically expands/contracts based on user inputs so I need an `apply()` function that counts the actual number of matrix columns, rather than using a fixed assumption of 4 columns per the above example. (And I'm not adding a value of 1 to the elements; I'm running the parallel minima function `test[,1] <- pmin(test1[,1], 5)` to say limit each value to a max of 5).

With my current limited understanding of the `apply()` family of functions, all I can so far do is `apply(test, 2, function(x) {return(x+1)})` but this is adding a value of 1 to all elements in all columns rather than only the odd-numbered columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may simply subset the input data frame to access only odd or even numbered columns.  Consider:

```r
test[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- apply(test[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 2, function(x) f(x))
test[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- apply(test[c(FALSE, TRUE)], 2, function(x) f(x))
```

This works because the recycling rules in R will cause e.g. `c(TRUE, FALSE)` to be repeated however many times is needed to cover all columns in the input `test` data frame.

For a matrix, we need to use the `drop=FALSE` flag when subsetting the matrix in order to keep it in matrix form when using `apply()`:

```r
test <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 4)
test[,c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- apply(test[,c(TRUE, FALSE),drop=FALSE], 2, function(x) x+1)
test

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    4    8   10
[2,]    3    5    9   11
[3,]    4    6   10   12
        ^         ^ ... these columns incremented by 1
```

Comment: When I run test[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- apply(test[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 2, function(x) {return(x+1)}), I get the error message "Error in apply... dim(X) must have a positive length". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 See the updated answer.  You may use the `drop=FALSE` flag when subsetting the matrix, to keep it in matrix form when using `apply`.  What is happening now is that the subset of the matrix is being coerced to a 1D integer vector, hence the `dim(X)` error message.

Comment: I see now, drop = FALSE. I had been making the incorrect assumption that since apply() is used for matrices, that it would retain a matrix form and not simplify to a 1D vector. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

You may use modulo `%% 2`.

```
odd <- !seq(ncol(test)) %% 2 == 0
test[, odd] <- apply(test[, odd], 2, function(x) {return(x + 1)}) 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    4    8   10
# [2,]    3    5    9   11
# [3,]    4    6   10   12
```

Comment: This code is giving me a matrix of [2,2,4, 5,5,7, 8,8,10, 11,11,13], and not the [2,3,4, 4,5,6, 8,9,10, 10,11,12] I'm looking for.  It needs to add a value of 1 to every element in each odd-numbered column only.

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 Just move `odd` to the other side of the comma, see edit.